# How to create query filter based on for-loop button clicked

Tags: html, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating a sample company web database, mainly with employee records and stuff. On one of the page, I want to display all the employees based on their department.

On my models, the department is a CharField choices. I can display the list of these departments by creating a list comprehension in views.py then forloop buttons on the html page with an href tag to the department's page. Now on this where I'm having difficulties. Clearly each element of the for loop will just get redirected to the same page no matter which button was clicked. I've tried to create a query filter and pass the actual department's name and this will work.

On my views i have this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Staff

def depts(request):
    deptList = Staff.department_list
    depts = [x[1] for x in deptList]
    return render(request, 'dsvstaff/depts.html',{'depts':depts})


def theStaffs(request):
    staffs = Staff.objects.filter(department='?')
    return render(request, 'dsvstaff/theStaffs.html',{'staffs':staffs})
```

Then on my Department list page:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
     {% for dept in depts %} 

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'theStaffs' %}">{{ dept }}</a>

      {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This page is where I'm having difficulties:

```
{% block content %}

    {% for x in staffs %}
        {{ x.first_name }} {{ x.last_name }} - {{ x.postion }}

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

What I wanted is to pass the name of the department's name in the query filter based on the button clicked.

Comment: What is `departement_list` here? Please share the relevant models.

Comment: Thanks @Willem Van Onsem. This actually is what I'm trying to achieve. The added parameter was all that needed. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an extra parameter to determine the departement:

```
def staff(request, department):
    staffs = Staff.objects.filter(department=department)
    return render(request, 'dsvstaff/theStaffs.html',{'staffs':staffs})
```

You will need to add this to the `urls.py` as well:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import staff

urlpatterns = [
    path('staff/<department>', staff, 'staff'),
    # ...
]
```

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% for dept in depts %} 
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'staff' department=dept %}">{{ dept }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

It however does not look like a good idea to store the department as a `CharField`. Since a department is an entity, it makes sense to define a model for this, such that you can refer to it like a `ForeignKey`. This will reduce the database size, make it easier to maintain the database, and it is easier to change the name of a department. See more on [*database normalization* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).